# Graph API SDK for .NET v6, C# Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, microsoft-graph-api

I've just installed Visual Studio Community and wanted to have a play around with C# (.net 6 LTS) and the graph API. I've created a winform for this purpose.

I've looked at the documentation and can see i need to install the SDK via nuget, but when i'm searching the repository i can't seem to see it.

Am i doing something silly?

Comment: If you search for Microsoft.Graph in the Nuget Package Manager within Visual Studio, you'll be able to find the needed package.
Is this what you need ? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/

Comment: is it, but it doesn't show up.

I'm going to Project > Manage NuGet Packagies, Switch to Browse and then use the search.  Using Graph or Microsoft.Graph gives no results.

Comment: Interestingly, under package source there is only visual studio offline packages

Answer (score 1):

It would seem the default install didn't include the online nuget packages. so i spotted an image on another site with the package source. Add it and can now see the packages as expected.

[image: nuget.org package source]